# How to echo other things then item from rss

Tags: php, rss

I have the following php script to echo items from a rss feed. But what if I want to echo other items as the normal title,date or description? In this case for example gdacs:alertlevel or gdacs:eventtype. The rss feed you can find here https://www.gdacs.org/xml/rss.xml

If you look into the mentioned XML - there is for example alertlevel or eventtype - how can I get it into my php file and echo it into my document?

```
$limit = 5;
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load(trim(file_get_contents('https://www.gdacs.org/xml/rss.xml')));
$feed = array();

foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array(

        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    );

    array_push($feed, $item);   
    if(count($feed) == $limit) {
        break;
    }
}
$now = new DateTime();

foreach($feed as $entry) {


    $title = $entry['title'];
    $link = $entry['link'];
    $description = $entry['desc'];
    $date = new DateTime($entry['date']);


    echo '<div class="storytitle" >' . $title . '</div> ';
    echo '<div class="content">' . $description. '</div>';
    echo '<div class="date">'. $description. '</div> ';

}
```

Comment: What about it? It looks like you are echoing $title and $description, if you need $date, echo that too. Please update your question to outline the exact issue you are having.

Comment: f you look into the mentioned XML - there is for example alertlevel or eventtype - how can I get it into my php file and echo it into my document?